# Numpy-like reduction of particular dimensions in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, dimensionality-reduction

With a numpy multidimensional arrays, it is easy to reduce particular axes with functions such as `np.mean` or `np.sum`. For example, `np.mean(X, axis=2,keepdims=False)` will eliminate the second axis.

**What if our data is in Pandas long-format DataFrame and we want to reduce a particular variable in a similar fashion?**

For example, consider a dataset with four columns: `A`,`B`,`C`, and `value`. `A`,`B`,`C` specify independent variables, and `value` specifies a dependent measure. If we wish to reduce the dataframe by eliminating `B` (i.e., averaging across all levels of `B`, but not within levels of `A` and `C`), we can use `df.groupby(['A','C']).mean()`. However, this solution becomes very clunky if there are many independent variables that we must enumerate in the `groupby` call.

**Does pandas have an efficient method for achieving numpy-like variable reduction?** In principle, one can convert the DataFrame into an xarray, but this seems like an overshoot.

Comment: why an overshoot? that's exactly what xarray is designed for...

Comment: Also [`Dataframe.to_xarray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray.html) makes the conversion quite straightforward as well. I'm a little unclear why the groupby solution becomes clunky, you can always programmatically build a list of columns to pass to groupby.

Comment: @HenryEcker - perhaps a conversion to an xarray, or a coding a function that builds the groupby args are the right solutions. However, since such a reduction is a very common data analytic operation, I was expecting that pandas would have a native way of doing it.

Comment: But you've outlined two of them. You can use groupby for efficient column-wise query-like operations, or if you want the efficiency of n-dimensional arrays, use `df.to_xarray()`. A DataFrame is not an N-D data structure, so there's no reason to expect it to perform like one. Give xarray a whirl - it's a great package!